# How to declare a typed object variable in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a Employees typescript interface:

```
export interface Employees {
  [employeeId: string]: {
    name: string
    gender: Gender
  }
}
```

How would I declare a variable `employees` that is of type `Employees`?

I have tried the following without success:

```
const employees: Employees{};
const employees: {Employees};
const employees: {}Employees;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. Read docs [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

`const employees: Employees = 'your object here'`;